# Deployment failed - No space left on device

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, samsung-mobile

I can't deploy an app anymore, because the system is telling me that there is no space left on the device. I checked with the "My files" app directly on the device and it states:

> Internal memory: 11,17 GB / 16,00 GB

That means that there are more than 4 GB left.

Error List:

> Error      ADB0000:  Deployment failed
>   Error      ADB0000: couldn't create file: No space left on device
>   Warning        Failed to delete package file: {0} One or more errors occurred.

Console Output:

```
1>Project "SomeProject.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):
1>Done building project "SomeProject.csproj".
1>SomeProject.Android -> C:\Projects\SomeProject\SomeProject\SomeProject.Android\bin\Debug\SomeProject.Android.dll
1>No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>Failed to delete package file: {0} One or more errors occurred.
1>ADB0000:  Deployment failed
1>Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: couldn't create file: No space left on device
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token) in E:\A\_work\488\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Util\AggregateAsyncResult.cs:line 72
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPush(IAsyncResult result) in E:\A\_work\488\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbSyncClient.cs:line 771
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
1>ADB0000: couldn't create file: No space left on device
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token) in E:\A\_work\488\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Util\AggregateAsyncResult.cs:line 72
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPush(IAsyncResult result) in E:\A\_work\488\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbSyncClient.cs:line 771
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
1>Done building project "SomeProject.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Build FAILED.
1>Deployment failed to Samsung SM-T390.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Device Log doesn't seem to update itself ...

What I tried:

- disconnected and reconnected the device via USB
- clean & rebuild
- restart device
- restart VS
- restart PC
- used the "hardware maintenance" app from Samsung to clear up free memory
- searching for the error in the internet

What else can I try and what can I do against it happening again?

**Update:**

Now I uninstalled other apps. Deployment worked only one time. Than I got

> FastDevDirectoryCreationFailed

I disabled fast deployment and I'm getting again

> No space left on device ...

Is resetting the device my only option? Or is this a bug with the build tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My only solution so far is to create new device in the emulator every time this happens. It keeps happening after I deployed my app several times (more that 50 deploys).

**Update**：

If you use android device.You can operate the factory-reset(open the settings=>System=>Reset optionss=>Erase all data(factory-reset)) to the  reset from the device.

If you use a android emulator, You can open Andorid Device manager, then delete the old one and create a new emulater.

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: @testing Thanks for your sharing. If the reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

To free space you just have to delete memory of the device. You can also try to clean the cache memory. At Settings > Storage/Memory > Stored Data Cache > Clean. If this doesn´t helps, you can try to run the app in the emulator of Microsoft Visual Studio, where you can set the memory of the phone. Go to the icon in the appbar of visual studio(open new android device) and there you can create a new one and set their preferences.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is only the "hardware maintenance" app on the device, which should clean the cache. App does run in "Android Emulator", but very slow. Thats the reason why I switched onto the device. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error today as well, though instead of cleaning up and removing stuff the easiest solution is to just set the disk size from 800M to 1600M in the device settings.

Answer (score 0):

try increasing ram size in device manager.
it was 700 MB made it 1000MB - and its worked...!